# Excel: find the Max of an array with same names

Tags: excel-formula

I have searched the Net and tried multiple solution which never worked. You are my last hope.
I have a table like that:

NAMES..........            VALUES

A...........................4

A...........................1

B...........................4

B...........................3

B...........................2

B...........................1

C...........................4

C...........................3

As you can see, the first column has names only where the second one values.
Both Names and Values often repeat them self.
The idea is to TAG the names (first column) with the MIN value taken from the second column.
So the correct result should be:

NAMES..........            VALUES

A...........................1

B...........................1

C...........................3

I am trying to do that through Excel using the INDEX+Match formula where I am trying to add a MIN formula without success:

=MIN(INDEX($D$25:$D$36,MATCH(C25,$C$25:$C$36,0),1))

I have put the MIN everywhere but none seems to work. Which is the correct syntax and if this is not the right solution, which formula might do the job?

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: The Pivot tables doesn't work, at least doesn't full fill the final goal.There are other fields which I need. Using the Pivot tables and adding the other fields I need will expand the Pivot Table as well with the result of having (again) too many unneeded records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A** and **B**, in **C1** through **C3** enter:
A
B
C
  then in **D1** enter the array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(A$1:A$100=C1,B$1:B$100,""))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

If the data never changes, a Pivot Table is easier to implement.

Comment: Gary! It seems to work!! Could you please explain the syntax and what exactly this formula does? I was sure that the correct formula to use was the Index+Min (according to what I had found on the net), while you came up with something apparently different. Thanks a lot

Comment: @fedone  The first equation says: *"get the minimum of column B, but only for those rows in which column A has the value **A**"*

Answer (score 0):

Two non-array alternatives.

With the newer MINIFS function.

```
=minifs(d:d, c:c, c25)
```

Using INDEX in its array format but entered as a standard formula,

```
=min(index((d$25:d$36)+(c$25:c$36<>c25)*1e99, , ))
```